# How to set the industry on a LinkedIn job post?

Tags: linkedin

We're a media company looking to post job openings on LinkedIn for a Copywriter and an Operations Manager.

I've posted jobs on LinkedIn before  but this is the first time I've encountered this issue.

I'm following LinkedIn's [instructions to post a job](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a517545/post-a-job-on-linkedin?lang=en), and I reach the 8th and final step, "Click 'Post Job'" without ever being presented with an option to identify the industry.

If I post the job, it is then incorrectly labeled as "Computer Software" which attracts the wrong candidates.

Does anyone know how to set or change the industry label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this LinkedIn BLOG post, *[4 Easy Ways to Improve Your LinkedIn Job Post Performance](https://www.linkedin.com/business/talent/blog/talent-acquisition/easy-ways-to-improve-your-linkedin-job-post-performance)*, the 'Company Industry' fields should be located near the 'Job Functions'.

They go on to note that if you can’t find your specific 'Industry', include the keywords in your job description.

[image]

In LinkedIn's support article titled, *[Edit your job post on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a517567/edit-your-job-post-on-linkedin?lang=en)*, there is a note highlighting that neither the 'Industry' nor the 'Seniority' fields can be edited once a job has been posted.

Perhaps you missed the 'Industry' field when first creating the jobs, and since they are not presented for editing (restricted) you are assuming they were missing all along.